Updating Scrollbar in Real-time for Draggable Circular Container in HTML Canvas with JavaScript
I'm developing a draggable circular container within a canvas in HTML and JavaScript, and I'm having difficulty getting the scrollbar to update automatically each time the user scrolls within the container. Although the container scrolls correctly, the scrollbar doesn't reflect these changes in real-time. How can I solve this issue to ensure that the scrollbar synchronizes properly with the movement of the content within the circular container?


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const resizeCanvas = () => {
    canvas.height = container.clientHeight;
    canvas.width = container.clientHeight;
}

let containerHeight, containerScrollHeight,scrolled, docHeight, scrollPer;

const render = () => {
    containerHeight = container.offsetHeight;
    containerScrollHeight = container.scrollHeight;
    scrolled = container.scrollTop;
    scrollPer = scrolled / (containerScrollHeight - containerHeight);
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    makeArc('#666666', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2.05, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    makeArc('#000000', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, canvas.height / 2.05, ((container.scrollTop - 0.1) * 2) * Math.PI, (container.scrollTop * 2) * Math.PI);
};

const makeArc = (color, one, two, three, four, five) => {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.arc(one, two, three, four, five);
    ctx.stroke();
};


resizeCanvas();
render();
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    resizeCanvas();
    render();
});
container.addEventListener('scroll', render);
:root{
  --item-size: 40dvw;
}
*{
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
html {
  scrollbar-width:none;
  -ms-overflow-style:none;
  overflow-y:-moz-scrollbars-none
}
.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width:0;
  display: none
}
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(185, 212, 235, 0.698);
}
section{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: calc(var(--item-size) + 5.9px);
  height: calc(var(--item-size) + 5.9px);
  gap: 2px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
main{
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 2px;
  overflow: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: auto;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main>.item{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 3px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
.canvas{
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0px; top: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hi</h1>
<section class="scrollbar" id="container">
<main>
  <div class="item">
    <p>hola</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>hola</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>hola</p>
  </div>
</main>
<canvas width="100" height="100" class="canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
</section>
</body>
</html>




i don't see a scrollbar

the container.addEventListener('scroll', render); is not doing what you think

#container has its overflow set to hidden, it won't scroll, you want to get the <main> element instead. Then scrollPer is never used, and the angles you pass to arc should probably be based on a ratio rather than directly scrollTop?

Your question is not too clear...
I'm going to focus on what I think is your problem, the "scroll" you want to create in my eyes is an arc that grows as the user scrolls in the page, but nothing is really happening.

your container.addEventListener('scroll', render) is not triggering

instead i'm going to use: container.addEventListener('wheel', scroll);


See working prototype below


const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let scrollValue = 0.2

const resizeCanvas = () => {
  canvas.height = container.clientHeight;
  canvas.width = container.clientHeight;
  render();
}

const scroll = (e) => {
  scrollValue += (e.deltaY > 0)? 0.5: -0.5
  scrollValue = Math.max(0.2, scrollValue)
  render()
}

const render = () => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  makeArc('gray', 2 * Math.PI);
  makeArc('red' , scrollValue);
};

const makeArc = (color, endAngle) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.arc(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2, canvas.height/2.05, 0, endAngle);
  ctx.stroke();
};

resizeCanvas();
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);
container.addEventListener('wheel', scroll);
:root {
  --item-size: 40dvw;
}

* {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

html {
  scrollbar-width: none;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow-y: -moz-scrollbars-none
}

.hide-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
  display: none
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(185, 212, 235, 0.698);
}

section {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: calc(var(--item-size) + 5.9px);
  height: calc(var(--item-size) + 5.9px);
  gap: 2px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 2px;
  overflow: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-behavior: auto;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main>.item {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 3px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
<body>
  <section class="scrollbar" id="container">
    <main>
      <div class="item">
        <p>aaa</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>bbb</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>ccc</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>ddd</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>eee</p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <p>fff</p>
      </div>
    </main>
    <canvas width="100" height="100" class="canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
  </section>
</body>



